# How does some second phone number apps like Sideline, Hushed work? what's the technical principle?

Tags: ios

Some apps like Sideline, Hushed, can be used in USA and Canada as a second phone number, what's the technical principle?

Comment: Please share why you want to understand this. Typically this is not a good StackOverflow (SO) question because it's very general. SO is for rather specific & detailed programming issues. [This StackExchange forum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=exchange+about+Voip) would have been appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Our app](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/numberbay-control-your-calls./id642013221?l=en&mt=8) [NumberBay](http://www.numberbay.com), does this for 60+ countries, including USA and Canada.* So I know what I'm talking about:

Calls are received on a virtual phone number (called a [DID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_inward_dial)).

DIDs are often purchased from 3rd party companies (like top-quality [Voxbone](http://www.voxbone.com) and our supplier). This is because deals must be made with government organisations and/or large telephony companies in every supported country. Also often infrastructure must be configured/rented/bought to support the connections. This is massive amount of work and very specialized.

When someone calls the DID, this call is received by this 3rd party and is forwarded (using [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol)) to the NumberBay/Hushed/Sideline server.

([VoIP (Voice over Internet Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP)  is the general terms for telephony using internet. SIP is a possible implementation/example of VoIP.)

This NumberBay/Hushed/Sideline server knows to which user account the called DID belongs and forwards the call to the user's device or phone number.

This forwarding can be done in two ways:

- SIP: The company's app will receive the call. Data will travel over Wi-Fi or mobile data. The company's server will 'call' the app. Hushed does this.
- Good old telephony: The company's server will forward (this is called 'termination') the call to the telephony network. Very big company may have their own connections into the telephony network, but often they have a contract with a termination party. Sideline does this, but seems to only call your mobile number. *[NumberBay](http://www.numberbay.com) goes much further allowing you to register all your mobile and fixed-line phone numbers in the app. You can select, per virtual number, which phone number you want NumberBay to forward the calls to.*

Let me know if you need more technical details.

Comment: The answer is exactly what I am looking for, thanks very much. This is the first time I asked questions on stackoverflow and I am lucky:)

Comment: This is what I figured, good to know the correct terms now. One question: if you say "forwards the call to the user's device or phone number." - does that mean my phone rings like it would ring when it is "normally" called? Which phone number do I see as a caller, do I see the one of whoever actually called or from system in the middle? I am assuming the caller will not know that the call was redirected to somewhere else!?

Comment: I have another question, according the description of sideline here: 
https://www.sideline.com/how-the-sideline-calling-app-works/     

It doesn't depend on sideline server to forward the calling because it can work only on "device’s regular cellular network".

"Unlike most calling apps that only work over Wi-Fi, Sideline uses the device’s regular cellular network. This gives you the same great call quality you get from your regular number. In other words, Sideline works anywhere your cell phone does."

Comment: @meaning-matters where do. you think your only upvote comes from? OP cannot yet upvote

Comment: @luk2302 Added answer.